# JSON Format Deserealize Error .NET

Tags: .net, json, winforms, json.net, deserialization

I'm kinda new to manipulating JSON format data retrieved through an API. I'm using JSON.NET to deserealize and for most JSON format data, it works, however, when I try to retrieve data from ETSY in JSON format, it gives an error...

```
Unexpected JSON token while reading DataTable: StartObject
```

This is the JSON data I am trying to get into a datatable...It's a sample data from ETSY's account.

```
{
    "count":1,
    "results": [{
        "user_id":5029420,
        "login_name":"EtsyStore",
        "creation_tsz":1282269739,
        "referred_by_user_id":null,
        "feedback_info": {
            "count":3038,
            "score":100
        }
    }],
    "params": {
        "user_id":"etsystore"
    },
    "type":"User",
    "pagination":{}
}
```

Here is my current code...

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim json As String = webClient.DownloadString("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/users/etsystore?api_key=apikey")
Dim table As DataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(json)
DataGridView1.DataSource = table
```

Can anybody help me sort this out? Thank you very much.

Comment: What are those [] for in your JSON code?

Comment: @Kilazur Hmmm I'm sorry but I'm not sure... That's the unedited data returned from ETSY's database through it's official API. Is that the problem?

Comment: No, that was curiosity. I use generated JSON files in a project and haven't seen those yet. Learning everyday!

Comment: [] denotes an array, {} an object. to [{}] = array with 1 entry in there being an object.

Comment: Yeah I get you, I can actually parse JSON format just fine, but I couldn't get it why JSON.NET can't get this. I'm pretty sure it's not a bug on JSON.NET.

Comment: @MarvinSmit Hi Sir. Do you know how to fix my problem? :)

Comment: Well, I don't see anything wrong and it gets validated on [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). That may well be a bug with your JSON.NET.

Comment: Yeah I checked JSONLint, it is valid. Hmmmmm, I don't get this anymore :(

Comment: After some searches: "Your object doesn't match the JSON. Read the documentation". Guess the incoming JSON cannot be deserialized into a DataTable type.

Comment: @MarvinSmit Is there any other way to deserialize it and show information in a datatable or dataset way?

Comment: Unfamiliar with VB.Net. in C# i would use a 'dynamic' object to deserialize into. Bottom line, you take over deserialization (partly) to get it into a 'DataTable'. More correctly would be to define an object which represents the data as incoming from the JSON. This can then be deserialized 'as normal'. Then 'transform/read/create' that into a DataTable, since that's required for your databind. Ain't native types annoying when you want some interop? :)

Comment: @MarvinSmit Yeah that was what I thought. But since there are too many data fields that I'm not familiar with that ETSY gives, this isn't gonna be easy, lol. Anyways, thank you very much for the help. I can do C# too, can you help me start a bit on this?

Comment: Basically use "dynamic dTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)" and take it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to deserialize into a `DataTable` or `DataSet`, Json.Net requires a very specific format as seen in this [example from the documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/DeserializeDataSet.htm).  Your JSON does not conform to this format, therefore it does not work.  This does not mean you can't use Json.Net, it just means that you need to choose some other way to deserialize.

One way is to create strongly typed classes, and deserialize into those:

```
Public Class RootObject
    Public Property count As Integer
    Public Property results As List(Of Result)
    Public Property params As Params
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property pagination As Pagination
End Class

Public Class Result
    Public Property user_id As Integer
    Public Property login_name As String
    Public Property creation_tsz As Integer
    Public Property referred_by_user_id As Object
    Public Property feedback_info As FeedbackInfo
End Class

Public Class FeedbackInfo
    Public Property count As Integer
    Public Property score As Integer
End Class

Public Class Params
    Public Property user_id As String
End Class

Public Class Pagination
End Class
```

Then:

```
Dim root As RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(json)
```

Alterntatively, you could deserialize into a `JObject` and use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to navigate and extract the data you need.  Here is [an example](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/QueryJsonSelectTokenWithLinq.htm) that might help with that.  There are many other examples in the documentation as well as here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi Sir :) Thank you very much for this help. I will try this, then report back to you. I appreciate it. Is there any JSON deserializing library that accepts ETSY's kind of format? Or I have no choice but to make classes to accept data before they are passed to the dataset class? Thank you very much.

Comment: There's nothing special about the ETSY JSON.  Any JSON library can deserialize it, including Json.Net.  It's just that you can't put it directly into a `DataTable` with Json.Net without writing your own converter for it.  You DO have a choice as to whether to create strongly-typed classes or not; that's what I said in my answer.  If you don't want to create classes, you can deserialize into a JObject instead.

Comment: Thank you Sir, Voted your answer up and Marked as answer. I appreciate it :) I got JObject to work. Can you check this link if you have time? Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403758/json-net-dynamic-parsing-more-efficient-solution

Comment: By the way, I looked at your other question and added an answer there.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Sir. I just got online. Holy cow thank you very much for it. I appreciate it. I honestly dont like asking questions, I prefer doing the answering, but yeah, sometimes I really just need help. Thank you. Will vote up your answer and mark it as answer once I get it to work :)