# JSON.NET Dynamic Parsing (More Efficient Solution)

Tags: .net, json, winforms, parsing, json.net

so I'm using JSON.NET to parse JSON data. I have got dynamic parsing using `JObject` class to work but I'm looking for a more efficient way. This is just the basics and my final solution will be much more complicated, but first thing's first, I need to get the basics.

So I have this JSON data...

```
{
    "count":1,
    "results": [{
        "user_id":5029420,
        "login_name":"EtsyStore",
        "creation_tsz":1282269739,
        "referred_by_user_id":null,
        "feedback_info": {
            "count":3038,
            "score":100
         }
     }],
     "params": {
         "user_id":"etsystore"
     },
     "type":"User",
    "pagination":{}
}
```

Here's my current code so far...I'd like to get the value of `user_id` under the `results` object.

```
Dim p1 = JObject.Parse(json)
Dim p2 = JObject.Parse(p1("results").ToString.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""))
MsgBox(p2("user_id"))
```

So I'm able to get the value of `user_id` but I don't think this is the most efficient way of doing it. Is there another way of doing it? Thank you very much :) If anyone already has the code, C# or VB.NET will do, but guidelines will just do fine for me, thank you :)

Comment: is the structure of JSON will change every-time or be static ?

Comment: it actually depends on what parameter I use for the ETSY API :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a JSON parser, you should not need to directly manipulate the JSON string (that is the job of the parser), nor parse the JSON more than once (the data is already in memory from the first parse).  So you are right, what you are doing is not the best way to extract the data.

Here is an example of how you can extract the `user_id` and other result data from the JSON using the [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (i.e. JObjects / JTokens).  Because `results` is an array in the JSON, I'm assuming there might not always be just one result, so I will use a loop here.

```vb
' load all the JSON data into a JObject
Dim p1 As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)

' loop over the "results" array to get each child object (result)
For Each result As JToken In p1("results").Children()

    ' extract the data from each result
    Dim userId As Integer = result("user_id").Value(Of Integer)()
    Dim loginName As String = result("login_name").ToString()
    Dim creationTsz As Long = result("creation_tsz").Value(Of Long)()

    ' the feedback info is one level further down
    Dim feedback As JToken = result("feedback_info")
    Dim feedbackCount As Integer = feedback("count").Value(Of Integer)()
    Dim feedbackScore As Integer = feedback("score").Value(Of Integer)()

    ' do something with the data; perhaps write it to the console
    Console.WriteLine("User ID: " + userId.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("Login Name: " + loginName.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("Creation TSZ: " + creationTsz.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("Feedback Count: " + feedbackCount.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine("Feedback Score: " + feedbackScore.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine()

Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this Sir, it really does work. I have one last question. What does (Of Integer) mean in result("user_id").Value(Of Integer)()? Let's say there are numerous array values under the `results` object and I'd like to search for a speficic `user_id`, do I have to loop through each array and use an `IF` statement or there's a search function provided by JSON.NET? Thank you very much :)

Comment: `(Of Integer)` basically tells Json.Net to cast the `Value` (the `user_id` in this case) to an Integer.  Otherwise you would not be able to assign it to the Integer variable.  To find a specific `user_id` you could either loop and use an `if` statement as you suggested, or you could use a LINQ query.

Comment: Okay Sir, that's good enough information. I will study LINQ. Your answer made my day :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization and De-serialization of JSON object is better approach for using json string and JSON object. This [Json converter](http://james.newtonking.com/json) is best suitable for  such operation. Simply De-serialize the JSON object to C# or VB instance and you will get access to all properties.

Comment: Thank you for this. I appreciate it :) Would you mind putting a bit of sample code to explain what you said better? Or convert my code to get the same answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to manipulate the JSON itself using string replace like you have done.

The cleanest way is to create a C# class with the same fields as the JSON you are parsing and deserializing to that as mentioned by Aaron. This makes the result a lot easier to use.

Alternatively you can leverage LINQ to JSON or dynamics to do something similar to your original answer without manipulating the JSON itself.

LINQ to JSON: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm

Dynamics: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer :) My first solution was to create a class like your first option, but then Brian Rogers told me about JObject which is now supported in the latest version of JSON.NET. So I think I'm going with this option. I will check your links. Thank you :)